# best way to create a linking table that contains an additional table of one of the entities its linking (look at my images) 

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating two tables with M:N realationship. One table is called user the other is edit (edit because it is an edit of an image or a text) a user can vote on edit and edit can have multiple votes so hence the linking table. When a user votes on an edit Its a vote that compares 2 edits so i want it to store the edit that is being compared. I wonder what is a nice way to implement that into a database.

So 2 edits get voted on by user and one is better than the other. I want to store both the value which got voted up which got voted down and the other edit that it was compared to.

Here is how my original design looks like: 
[image: original table]

and here is a solution I came up with please tell me if this is a good way of acomplishing what i want: 
[image: solution]

Comment: So a "vote" is not a straight up or down vote, it's actually a comparison between two edits, correct?

Comment: correct (well its also a vote up/down but its also a comparison)

Comment: @Xitcod13; Not quite sure, could you post `1. Code for the two FKs` between `edit_edit and edt_has_vote` `2. Expand these abbreviations, like (pjt_edt, edt_edv)` -- not part of my english repertoire.

Comment: pjt stands for project (there is additional table called project_pjt and the abriviations at the end like _pjt are part of my naming convention) so edv stands for edit has vote. usr stands for user. edt stands for edit. the yellow keys are PK and the red ones are FK. (the code is autogenerated by workbench program)

Answer (score 0):

- There is a UNIQUE index (alternate key) (AK) on `NewDocument` `(DocumentID, DocumentType)`; the foreign key from `Document` table `(DocumentID, DocumentType)` points here. This is used to lock-in the document type for a given `DocumentID`.Once you open a new document, place version 1 in the `Document` table.
- Place a check constraint on `EditVotes` for `Version_B > Version_A`

[image]

Comment: hey could you strip your diagram of all the unecessairly elements and make your diagram with user table,  linking table and edit table (instead of document table etc) .It shouldnt be that much work for you and  I want to make sure that i am doing it right before i implement it in my final design

Comment: I would post my diagram  but i am on a diffrent computer since i am traveling atm

Comment: @Xitcod13; well I do not quite understand your app completely. This model has certain data - integrity. I do not understand all your definitions. What is an edit? To me, an edit of a text is a text, an edit of an image, is an image, hence the subtype/ supertype. So votes are cast in between two versions of a same Document (Img or text).

Comment: Alright I think understand everything but the version_A and version_B I do not understand what are the 2 foreign keys for??

Comment: @Xitcod13 Vote compares two versions of a document. For example, vote for (DocNo: 7 ver 2) versus (DocNo 7 ver 3). So, first FK is `(DocumentID, Version_A)` and second FK is `(DocumentID, Version_B)` both reference `Document (DocumentID, DocumentVersion)`; first references (7,2) and the other one (7,3)

Comment: @Xitcod13; the order of PK in `EditVotes` should be `(DocumentID, Version_A, Version_B, VotedBy)`; did not notice change in order -- does not matter much on logical level..

Comment: @Xitcod13; One for each version. `(DocumentID, Version_A)` has to exists in `Document` and `(DocumentID, Version_B)` has to exists in `Document`

Comment: I edited my question could you tell me if this is what you had in mind or not??